# 32bit bmp image doesn't show up on pygame's screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm building a game and I'm trying to show up a little picture in the middle bottom of the screen. 
I can't understand why I don't see the image at all?

This is my picture class code which in a file called devil.py:

```
import pygame

class Devil():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        """Initialize the devil and set its starting position"""
        self.screen=screen

        #Load the devil image and get its rect
        self.image=pygame.image.load('images/devil.bmp')
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect=screen.get_rect()

        #Start each new devil at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.centerx=self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom=self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the devil at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

And this is my main code which is written in another file:

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from devil import Devil

def run_game():
    #Initialize pygame, settings and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    dvs_settings=Settings()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode(
        (dvs_settings.screen_width, dvs_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Devil vs Shitty")

    #Make a devil
    devil=Devil(screen)

    #Start the main loop the game.
    while True:

        #Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        #Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        screen.fill(dvs_settings.bg_color)  
        devil.blitme()

        #Make the most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
 run_game()
```

And this is my settings class in a file called settings.py:

```
class Settings():
    """A Class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings"""
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1000
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color=(230,230,230)
```

I can't find what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I only replaced the image and the `settings` stuff and it works correctly for me. Please add the relevant variables from the `settings` module as well. Perhaps something is wrong with the image. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @skrx I've added the settings code. I don't get any error messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem - which is a very strange one:
When I was editing my image, I saved it as a 32bit bmp file (The default option was 24 bit, and I thought to myself "I'm using 32bit python, I think it will match better).
But when I tried to show up my image in pygame - it didn't show up. 
I've tried anything. And in the end I tried to edit again the image.

Now, I saved it as a 24bit bmp and it works well!!!

Comment: 32 bit means [that there is just an extra byte used as padding in BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369649/how-to-convert-32-bit-bmp-to-contain-alpha-channel) (8 bit pr. channel). It's not related to the bitness of your python installation. My guess is that the BMP loader in pygame doesn't support 32-bit BMPs (.. which are kind of useless, as there are many formats that do everything BMP does, but does it better)

Comment: I was about to suggest to use another format like .png (also because bmp files are rather large), but forgot to post that. Good that you've figured it out yourself.